# Getting nano nanorc settings to work with "sudo nano" command

Tags: command-line, sudo, nano

Anyone know how to get nanorc settings (syntax highlighting, mouse) to work when using the "sudo nano" instance of the editor?

It works as expected when not using nano as a super-user but not with sudo in the mix.

I have all the desired settings in ~/.nanorc, as well as /etc/nanorc, but when editing a file with sudo, none of the personalized settings are applied.

Comment: When using `nano` through the mechanism of `sudo` none of your personalized settings are applied because it is not _you_ executing `nano`, rather it is the superuser. Try setting the desired setting in `/root/.nanorc` instead.

Comment: I edit `/etc/nanorc`. I **don't** edit `/root/.nanorc` even if it exists.

Comment: @DKBose `/etc/nanorc` affects all users of the computer. You should take it into account in a multi-user environment.

Comment: Your settings might be overriding using `/root/.nanorc` move it somewhere else to see what happens: `sudo mv /root/.nanorc{,.bk}`

Comment: @Melebius, thanks for explaining. I didn't know that.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver, Thank you. That sorted it. I simply did the following `sudo cp ~/.nanorc /root/.nanorc`. Seems to have done the trick. Incidentally, @DK Bose, I had edited `/etc/nanorc` with the desired settings but it still failed to use them in the sudo instance. Only having a `/root/` specific `.nanorc` seems to work — for me, in any case.

Comment: Glad to help. Do you want an answer for this?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver. Absolutely. Do you want to do the honors? Or would you prefer I recap it?

Comment: I'll take a go at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using an interactive shell, and then using `sudo` to execute a command, such as `nano`, the current user's settings in application specific configuration files are not sourced. So, in this case, `~/.nanorc` is not sourced, and the settings are not read.

The same condition occurs when the user uses `su` to switch to another user, including `root`. In both cases the new, or effective, user's settings are loaded instead. So using `sudo nano`, or using `su` to become `root` and then executing `nano`, will source the `/root/.nanorc` for *user* settings. The settings in the global configuration file, such as `/etc/nanorc`, affect all users on the system and should only be used to set global settings, which the user's file may override anyway.

To cause the effect you are looking for you need to apply the specialized setting to `/root/.nanorc`. Then when you `sudo nano` the settings for `root` will be applied rather than the settings found in `~/.nanorc`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with, e.g.:

```
sudo nano --rcfile ~/.nanorc <file-to-edit>
```

To make this more convenient, you can do:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias nano='nano --rcfile ~/.nanorc'
```

The first alias (for `sudo`) is a standard technique to allow `sudo` to expand users' aliases.

With these lines, you can use `sudo nano <file-to-edit>` as normal and your `$HOME/.nanorc` will be read.

Comment: Very flexible, except, you'd probably want to use a static  path to the .nanorc file (like `alias nano='nano --rcfile /home/myUserName/.nanorc'`) instead of using `~`. That way it won't look in the root home directory for `.nanorc`.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx -- as I explicitly wrote in the answer, if you use these lines your own (`sudo`-issuing) user's `$HOME/.nanorc` is used.  This is because the tilde (`~`) is expanded first.

Comment: You're right. It is expanded first (I didn't know that). (But don't use `sudo su` before the command instead of `sudo`, without a static path).